# Recital-style program code returns 0.0 when no output is needed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that reads numbers from standard input but when the user enters zero, the program recites all the numbers entered (excluding the zero). My code so far works for most cases i can think of; except when the number 0 is inputted. This is my code thus far:

```
user_input = float(input("Number: "))
ls = []
bs = []
ls.append(user_input)

# Keep getting inputs
while user_input != 0.0:
    user_input = float(input("Number: "))

    # Don't add the 0
    if user_input != 0.0:
        ls.append(user_input)

if user_input == 0.0:
    bs.append(user_input)

# Print them all back out in order:
print("")
print("Your numbers were:")
i = 0
while len(ls) > i:
        print(ls[i])
        i += 1
```

When 0 is given as the input; this is returned

```
Number: 0

Your numbers were:
0.0
```

when i need:

```
Number: 0

Your numbers were:
```

Comment: Because you ask for user input at the top, `user_input = float(input("Number: "))` and unconditionally ad it to your list.

Comment: as an aside, don't us a while-loop to loop over your list, just use `for item in ls: print(item)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments, line number 3 should be :

```
if user_input > 0 :ls.append(user_input)
```

Comment: worked! had to use !=0 instead of >0 because i needed negative numbers too :) thank you